# can not install my wifi HP printer 2049

Tags: printer, hp

I tried to install my HP 2049 printer on EOS with hplip, but I get the error message that my firewall is blocking it. But I don't use a firewall in EOS.

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please go to the printer, consult its manual, and collect the IP address it uses. You will need that to solve your problem. If it doesn't use the same gateway IP address, you will need to amend the printer settings so it does. A search of HP Support shows no '2049' model, so please go to https://support.hp.com/us-en/printer , scroll down to _Identify your printer for manuals and specific product information_ and enter the printer serial number there to find your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the message: "printer rejects jobs"?

I had this bug too. You have to activate the printer in the CUPS settings: http://localhost:631 in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect though the wifi it might be the router's firewall blocking it.